# All these projectiles going in 1 direction

Tags: animation, lua, directions, love2d, projectile

Guys so basicaly i have this pieces of code in different locations(didnt want to post all code here) in Lua . I want to make a game on love2d. and my problem is: my projectiles are always going in 1 direction. i even make projectile.animnumber but still it gets to go in 1 direction. is there any way to split this massive. (I'm a newbie so don't flame me too much)

```
projectile = {}
   projectile.width = 30
   projectile.height = 32
   projectile.animNumber = 1    


function love.keyreleased(key)
        if (key == "space") then
            shoot()
            love.audio.play(magic_shotSND)

            if player.animNumber == 1 then 
                projectile.animNumber = 1

            elseif player.animNumber == 2 then 
                projectile.animNumber = 2

            elseif player.animNumber == 3 then 
                projectile.animNumber = 3

            else 
                projectile.animNumber = 4
            end

        end
    end

    -----

    for i,v in ipairs(player.shots) do
            if projectile.animNumber == 1 then 
                v.x = v.x + 300 * dt

            elseif projectile.animNumber == 2 then 
                v.x = v.x - 300 * dt

            elseif projectile.animNumber == 3 then 
                v.y = v.y + 300 * dt

            else 
                v.y = v.y - 300 * dt

            end
        end


    ----


    function shoot()
        local shot = {}
        shot.x = player.x - 16
        shot.y = player.y - 8
        table.insert(player.shots, shot)
    end


    for i,v in ipairs(player.shots) do 
            love.graphics.draw(skull, v.x, v.y)
        end
```

Comment: Probably, you have two different `projectile` tables?

Comment: What's "projectile"? It's a random word written in your code. I think you meant to return projectile from shoot()

Comment: projectile is an object. i used it to describe behavior.  
forgot to add.  

projectile = {}
   projectile.width = 30
   projectile.height = 32
   projectile.animNumber = 1

Comment: Player animnumber is the variable i use to recognise player last movement direction so he would use the right angle for animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all of your "projectile.animNumber" to "v.animNumber"

I think the problem is this:

```
for i,v in ipairs(player.shots) do
    if projectile.animNumber == 1 then 
        v.x = v.x + 300 * dt

    elseif projectile.animNumber == 2 then 
        v.x = v.x - 300 * dt

    elseif projectile.animNumber == 3 then 
        v.y = v.y + 300 * dt

    else 
        v.y = v.y - 300 * dt

    end
end
```

In your for loop you are checking for projectile.animNumber which doesn't appear previously in your code. Therefore, making the else statement true and causing all projectiles to travel in 1 direction.

Sorry if it was confusing; I'm not that good at explaining things